# Disk corruption caused by rsync'ing a large number of small files to external HDD with NTFS format

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ntfs, rsync, filesystem-corruption

I am noticing a weird phenomenon when transferring a large number of small files (hundreds of thousands pictures, for example) to an external HDD with `rsync`: It always leads to an IO error as shown below (output of `dmesg`):

```
[102560.315796] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2088 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[102560.315800] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 5, async page read
[102560.315868] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2184 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[102560.315870] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 17, async page read
[102560.315877] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2120 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[102560.315878] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 9, async page read
[102560.315935] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2088 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[102560.315936] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 5, async page read
[102560.315944] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 5, async page read
[102560.315956] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 17, async page read
[102560.315965] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 5, async page read
[102560.315972] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 5, async page read
[102560.315979] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 5, async page read
```

The HDD then becomes not mountable, but every time this happened I was able to fix it using `ntfsfix` so I doubt it is a hardware problem. `ntfsfix` output is shown below:

```
Mounting volume... $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 0...OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdc1 was processed successfully.
```

So I am really curious what could lead to so frequent HDD corruptions even for the most basic file IO operations. HDD corruption has happened over 20 times during the last two days. Is it the system, or `rsync`, or the disk itself?

Another weird pehenomenon: after rsync'ing a lof of files, even if no IO error happens, unmounting the disk takes very long (~10 minutes).

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and the HDD is a Seagate SDC003 (2TB, formatted as NTFS).

---

Update: The output of `smartctl -a`. I ran this right after yet another `rsync` failure.

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-69-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 2.5 5400
Device Model:     ST2000LM015-2E8174
Serial Number:    WDZXFWCV
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0e08ae450
Firmware Version: 0001
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jun 16 16:28:00 2023 CST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 326) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   075   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       30523320
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       449
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   071   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       13036046
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       6120 (197 141 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       90
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   052   047   040    Old_age   Always       -       48 (Min/Max 47/48)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       11
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1715
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   048   053   000    Old_age   Always       -       48 (0 13 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       175 (86 165 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       5808417042
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1793836935
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Also useful to see smartctl after it shows a failure. Does't it simply overheat, for example?

Comment: Is exact same issue every time? I mean this: "Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED"